# Devise 3.2.4 breaking custom RegistrationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've had the following setup to send the user a welcome email after a successful registration.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    super
    unless @user.invalid?
      UserMailer.delay.welcome(@user)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm on Rails 4.1.4 and I recently updated all gems, which updated Devise to 3.2.4. After the update, the above started throwing the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Seems like calling super is what is breaking things.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't Devise fault, but rather the following Turbolinks change broke redirect_to https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/commit/153f1b0f04c718442cfd73365a2778dfe1a1c5c7

Rolling back to Turbolinks 2.2.2 or 3f2b6e752acde1d9a59a75c48401dfb152afe154 solved the problem.